# Scaling items and rendering

Tags: c++, qt

I am making a small game in C++11 with Qt. However, I am having some issues with scaling.

The background of my map is an image. Each pixel of that image represents a tile, on which a protagonist can walk and enemies/healthpacks can be.

To set the size of a tile, I calculat the maximum amount like so (where imageRows & imageCols is amount of pixels on x- and y-axis of the background image):

```
QRect rec = QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry();
int maxRows = rec.height() / imageRows;
int maxCols = rec.width() / imageCols;
if(maxRows < maxCols){
    pixSize = maxRows;
} else{
    pixSize = maxCols;
}
```

Now that I have the size of a tile, I add the background-image to the scene (in `GameScene ctor`, extends from [`QGraphicsScene`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html)):

```
auto background = new QGraphicsPixmapItem();
background->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/images/map.png").scaledToWidth(imageCols * pixSize));
this->addItem(background);
```

Then for adding enemies (they extend from a [`QGraphicsPixMapItem`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicspixmapitem.html)):

```
Enemy *enemy = new Enemy();
enemy->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/images/enemy.png").scaledToWidth(pixSize));
scene->addItem(enemy);
```

This all works fine, except that on large maps images get scaled once (to a height of lets say 2 pixels), and when zooming in on that item it does not get more clear, but stays a big pixel. Here is an example: the left one is on a small map where pixSize is pretty big, the second one has a pixSize of pretty small.

[image: Image on a small map]
[image: Same QGraphicsPixMapItem on a large map]

So how should I solve this? In general having a pixSize based on the screen resolution is not really useful, since the `QGrapicsScene` is resized to fit the [`QGraphicsView`](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5-snapshot/qgraphicsview.html) it is in, so in the end the view still determines how big the pixels show on the screen.

```
MyGraphicsView w;
w.setScene(gameScene);
w.fitInView(gameScene->sceneRect(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to look at the [chip example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-chip-example.html) from Qt (link to Qt5 but also works for Qt4).

The thing that might help you is in the [chip.cpp file](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-chip-chip-cpp.html):

in the `paint` method:

```
const qreal lod = option->levelOfDetailFromTransform(painter->worldTransform());
```

where `painter` is simply a `QPainter` and `option` is of type `QStyleOptionGraphicsItem`. This quantity gives you back a measure of the current zoom level of your `QGraphicsView` and thus as in the example you can adjust what is being drawn at which level, e.g.

```
if (lod < 0.2) {
    if (lod < 0.125) {
        painter->fillRect(QRectF(0, 0, 110, 70), fillColor);
        return;
    }

    QBrush b = painter->brush();
    painter->setBrush(fillColor);
    painter->drawRect(13, 13, 97, 57);
    painter->setBrush(b);
    return;
}
```

[...]

```
if (lod >= 2) {
    QFont font("Times", 10);
    font.setStyleStrategy(QFont::ForceOutline);
    painter->setFont(font);
    painter->save();
    painter->scale(0.1, 0.1);
    painter->drawText(170, 180, QString("Model: VSC-2000 (Very Small Chip) at %1x%2").arg(x).arg(y));
    painter->drawText(170, 200, QString("Serial number: DLWR-WEER-123L-ZZ33-SDSJ"));
    painter->drawText(170, 220, QString("Manufacturer: Chip Manufacturer"));
    painter->restore();
}
```

Does this help?